# What's the pinout of the Gravity MOSFET power controller board?

Tags: power

I found https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Gravity__MOSFET_Power_Controller_SKU__DFR0457 this board for a non-Arduino project and it does not list the pinout of the JST-PH 2.0 header but it does show it connected to an Arduino so I was hoping people familiar with the Arduino could figure out based on that.

Comment: What's hard to understand about that wiring diagram?

Comment: It's right [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Arduinolibrary/DFRobot_Gravity_MOSFET_Power_Controller/master/Schematic.pdf). P1 is the "Gravity" connector. Pin 1 is the control signal (connected to an LED and an optical isolator that switches the MOSFET), Pin 2 is Vcc, Pin 3 is GND.